# Better way to do array of bools in JavaScript for nested collections

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, angularjs

I know there must be a better way to do this. I have a couple nested collections of javascript objects.

```
Objects
   Field1
     Value
   Field2
     Value
   Field3
     Value
Objects2
   Field1
     Value
   Field2
     Value
   Field3
     Value
Objects3
   Field1
     Value
   Field2
     Value
   Field3
     Value
```

I need to get to the values of the Fields of Object 1, 2, and 3 and check if they are true or false. Here is the code I am using now.

```
var valid = [];
if (objects instanceof Array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var fieldIsFull = [];
        // Loop through all fields to check if empty and build array
        for (var j = 0; j < objects[i].Fields.length; j++) {
            if (objects[i].Fields[j].isRequired) {
                if (objects[i].Fields[j].Value != null ||
                    objects[i].Fields[j].Value != undefined) {
                    fieldIsFull.push(true);
                } else {
                    fieldIsFull.push(false);
                }
            }
        }

        // Check array for any false value.
        if ($.inArray(false, fieldIsFull) >= 0) {
            valid.push(false);
        } else {
            valid.push(true);
        }
}
// Check array for any false value.
if ($.inArray(false, valid) >= 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

There must be a better way to do what I am doing. Can anyone help me out with a more efficient way to do this?

**SOLUTION:**
Here is the code I ended up with, seeing as I only need the false value.

```
if (objects instanceof Array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        // Loop through all fields to check if empty
        for (var j = 0; j < objects[i].Fields.length; j++) {
            if (objects[i].Fields[j].isRequired) {
                if (objects[i].Fields[j].Value == null) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Both answers (Andrew and Pointy) were great. But in the end I only need the false value. No operations on the actual values necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your function doesn't return the inner values of the array. If that's the case, exit early - when you would do `fieldIsFull.push(false);`, instead just `return false;`. Return `true` if it makes it to the end of the function. You can remove any line dealing with the `fieldIsFull` and `valid` arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build an array; you can just keep track of whether you've seen any `false` values with boolean operations. You also don't need to compare to both `null` and `undefined`, as `!=` will convert `undefined` to `null` for you.

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var allGood = true;
    // Loop through all fields to check if empty and build array
    for (var j = 0; allGood && j < objects[i].Fields.length; j++) {
        if (objects[i].Fields[j].isRequired) {
            allGood = allGood && objects[i].Fields[j].Value != null;
        }
    }

    valid.push(allGood);
}
```

*edit* — yes what the other answer from @AndrewVarnerin says is true - as soon as you find a `false` (empty) "Value", just `return false;` immediately, since that's what the function will do eventually anyway. However, if you're going to add code to do something for each empty value, then you'll want to loop through everything (and if so you'd take the test on "allGood" out of the `for` loop above).